# Verifying an index exists in Python lists and multidimensional lists

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, python-3.7, multi-index

I have a list of indexes that are either:

```
// Depending on type of list and inputs
single list index check: (x)
2d list index check: (x, y)
3d list index check: (x, y, z)
```

A variable takes in those indexes mentioned above and then I need to verify that the index exists in the specific list (which can be 1, 2, 3 or more dimensions):

```
// Examples of lists to check
list_1d = [1, 2, 3]
list_2d = [(1,1), (1, 2), ...]
```

etc.

I need a function or way to tell if my input index check with the list of indexes has a value in the actual list. Like for example, in a two dimensional list I get (1, 2) passed in I need to verify if there is an index at [1][2] with a true or false. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try iterating through every single index and, for each one, try to retrieve the value that corresponds, which can then be used in the next iteration. If any of them fail, then it should return `False`.

```py
def check_indexes(list_indexes, multidimentional_list):
    """ Checks if a list of indexes recursively exist for a multi-dimentional list
    """
    current_list = multidimentional_list
    
    for index in list_indexes:
        try:
            current_list = current_list[index]
        except IndexError:
            return False
    
    return True
```

Comment: Yes I was attempting to do something similar like that but had issues with the iterations

Comment: Do you mean that this approach does not work for you?